# Macbook Air (2013) trackpad not responding

Tags: trackpad, catalina, nvram

The trackpad fails to respond after the computer got hung on a website video last night and then went into sleep mode.  On wakeup I had to use the arrow keys to toggle through various apps and quit them, then held down power button to allow shutdown. It took 3 times through this routine before I got all apps shutdown before a shutdown.  On restart, STILL no trackpad.

Just installed Catalina a week ago.  No problems with trackpad initially, probably unrelated to Catalina?

I can use a USB or wireless mouse.   I ran Disk First Aid, no help, no problems found.  Should I reset the PRAM or something? How is that done?   -- hold down P, R, command and option on restart bong?  Cannot recall.

Comment: Take a look at [this site](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/reset-macs-smc-pram/) to learn how to do a SMC reset, it might help.

Answer (score 1):

I tried SMC reset guided by the excellent Apple tech support.  But it did not solve the problem.  Just as PRAM zapping did not.

His suggestion of removing 2 plist items from the library did solve(!) the problem.

- ~/Library/preferences/com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad.plist
- ~/Library/preferences/com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad.plist

Apparently, one of these two got damaged; trashing them with a RESTART generates fresh plist files. Problem solved, thanks Apple!

Comment: Which 2 plist files ? Could you add their file paths ? At least their names, if they're in trash  ?

Comment: 2 FILE NAMES: com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad.plist  & com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad.plist

Comment: file path for AppleMultitouchTrackpad is: Username/Library/preferences

Comment: file path for AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad is SAME.

Comment: you can accept the answer too if you're not looking for more :) Also, bold is preferable to all capital letters (which looks like shouting) .